# Nvidia Geforce GTX 860M video card not recognized by Linux - Asus Republic of Gamers

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I have a new laptop by Asus Republic Of gamers.

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on this laptop but now there is a problem with the video card not being even recognized by the system.

In Bios there is no option to activate/deactivate the video card.

There are a lot of workarounds on the internet but none of them mention how to make the VGA Controller to recognize this video card. I guess if I manage to make this work everything else should be easy to follow.

```
lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0416] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:157d]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    Memory at ed400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

and

```
lspci | grep -i nvidia
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev ff)
```

and

```
lspci -v

...

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
    !!! Unknown header type 7f

...
```

Comment: You’ll probably need to [install Bumblebee](http://askubuntu.com/questions/452556/how-to-set-up-nvidia-optimus-bumblebee-in-14-04) and friends.

Comment: i did do that but still the same